# How can I tell which of multiple network cards is in use using C#?

Tags: c#, network-programming, ping

How can I know which client IP is used for communication to the server in C# if I have multiple network cards in client system (so that there will be multiple IP addresses too) ?
**I would like to get private IP (not the public IP)** .

```
                                   OR
```

Please be patient to read the details...

Suppose I have multiple network cards connected to my PC, how can I know which card is used for communication. For example, if I use

```
ping 192.168.x.xxx
```

I would like to know which card (and which IP address) used for communication.

The command

```
netstat
```

will tell us about the active connections. I am not interested in active connections, but I would like to know which card will be used for next connection. That is, if we use `ping` which card (or IP address) will be used ?

How can I get the same IP address using C# (because I would like to do some stuff in WCF which needs endpoint IP addresses )?

For example, I would like to use the IP(as LocalIP) and port(as ListeningPort) to create the following

```
net.tcp:// + LocalIP + ":" + ListeningPort + "/Service/ep1;
```

A reference of the query can be found at...
https://superuser.com/questions/304372/how-can-i-tell-which-of-multiple-network-cards-is-in-use

Comment: Do you want the routing table information? [This might be the API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374019.aspx) you need.

Comment: Once a connection is open you can query for the IP addresses at either end. It sounds like it's the IP address that is of interest rather than the details of the physical interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to remote host using [Socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx)  and set specific IP address using [Bind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.bind.aspx) method.